# Two administrators for one app

Tags: administrator, facebook-apps

We are two programmers that have written one facebook app.
We both want to be administrator of this page and also we want to be able to remove the other one as admin with his CONFIRMING permission.
Is there any way to do this ?

or if it's not possible what is the way that a group has one app.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can both be administrators of your application, but if one removes the other from the admin list, there won't be any confirmation request sent to the removed guy.

Go on https://developers.facebook.com/apps, select your application, then click "Edit Roles", and put the uid of the other guy, or his name if he is in your friend list.